# Listbox using class module

Tags: arrays, module, listbox, vb6

In visual basic 6.0 , I am working about array and listbox. I want that when I click the command button all the string values will be displayed in the listbox, thus I wanted to use objects from class and call this in the form. I would like to know how to call the string values for listbox from a class module to the form.

I already tried the string array but only for messagebox.I dont know how to use the listbox.I can show what I did. I created a method friendslist() using class1. As seen there I used messagebox I want to replace it with the text.Then Call those text it in command1_click() as the value for listbox

```
Dim friends(5) As String
friends(0) = "Anna"
friends(1) = "Mona"
friends(2) = "Marie"
friends(3) = "Kent"
friends(4) = "Jona"
friends(5) = "Fatima"

For a = 0 To 5
MsgBox "Your friends are: " & friends(a)
Next
End Sub

Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim myfriends As New Class1
Call myfriends.friendslist

End Sub
```

This is my expected output

[image: Form1]

Answer (score 1):

You could pass a ListBox as a parameter to friendslist() method.

```
' insert this code into Class1
Public Sub FriendsList(oList As ListBox)
    Dim a As Long
    Dim friends(5) As String
    friends(0) = "Anna"
    friends(1) = "Mona"
    friends(2) = "Marie"
    friends(3) = "Kent"
    friends(4) = "Jona"
    friends(5) = "Fatima"

    oList.Clear
    For a = LBound(friends) To UBound(friends)
        oList.AddItem friends(a)
    Next a
End Sub

' insert this code into form
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim oFriends As Class1
    Set oFriends = New Class1
    oFriends.FriendsList List1    ' instead of List1, type the actual name of ListBox control
    Set oFriends = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: smith thank you so much, and how am I going to call it in the form?

Comment: I've edited my post so there's an example of form code.